# Why cannot the verb 'consider' theta-mark 'Frederick' as the Theme?

Tags: syntax

<sub>Source: p 335. *Syntax, A Generative Introduction* (3 ed, 2012) by Andrew Carnie.</sub>

> [...] Take the active sentence in (ii):
>
> ii) Wilma considers [Fredrick to be foolish].
>
> In this sentence, *Wilma* is the experiencer of *consider*, and **[1.]** *Fredrick* is the
> external theta role of the predicate *is foolish* **[End of 1.]**. When *consider* is made into a
> passive, the subject of the lower clause raises to become the subject of the
> main clause:

iii) Fredrick is considered *t<sub>i</sub>* to be foolish.

> **[2.]**  Notice that Fredrick is never theta-marked by the verb *consider* **[End of 2.]**. As such
> there is no way to make it the external argument like in (i). Because of
> cases like (iii), the movement account is preferred.

I do not understand 1 and 2. Why cannot 'Frederick' be the Theme of the transitive verb 'consider'? If so, then Frederick would be theta-marked, contrary to 2.

Comment: I don't know either. Maybe Andrew Carnie has some peculiar algorithm for assigning theta roles. It would be better to ask him.

Comment: No, Carnie is right/consistent within that theory of syntax. There are two clauses, [Frederick] belongs to the second clause, not the first one.

Comment: Cf. consider1: You never consider my feelings (theta-marked, one clause) vs. consider2: I consider him to be foolish (two clauses).

Comment: Yep. *Frederick* is not the object of the verb (\* *Wilma considers Frederick*), but the whole clause is;as AlexB said, *Frederick to be foolish* is a clause on its own of which *Frederick* is the theme and thus you can not segregate *Frederick* and assign him a theta role from the first clause; if so, then you should do so with the whole clause. One might assume *consider* to have two different lexicon entries, one taking an NP (*Wilma considers [this idea]*) and one a clause (*Wilma considers [Frederick to be foolish]*), where the whole clause is the object (and thus the theta-role asignee).

Comment: @lemontree An alternative analysis would be to see this as a complex catenative construction where "Frederick" is the 'raised' object of "consider". "Frederick" is not an argument of "consider"; he is of course the syntactic direct object of "consider", but only the 'understood' subject of the subordinate clause. The catenative complement is thus "to be foolish", not "Frederick to be foolish" for the latter is not a constituent, but a sequence of direct object + complement.

Comment: @Alex B. I'd say that "Frederick" belongs in the matrix clause as syntactic object of "consider". See my message above to lemontree.

Comment: @lemontree It is the DO according to very many modern grammars. Consider the passivisation "Frederick is considered to be foolish" and not *"Frederick to be foolish is considered".

Comment: @Araucaria Good point +1. The problem is many would agree but then say that the object is not just 'Frederick', but 'Frederick to be foolish'. It is then necessary to _prove_ that "Frederick" + "to be foolish" are separate constituents. I'd use the pseudo-cleft test; what about you?

Comment: @BillJ This has been the standard analysis of ECM constructions since Chomsky's Barriers (1986).  If you believe your analysis is correct, provide sources from the literature.

Comment: @Ink Huddleston & Pullum's award-winning The Cambridge Grammar Of The English Language. That good enough for you?

Comment: @BillJ I haven't heard of the pseudo-cleft test, I don't think, but I can guess how that might work. My brain feels like it's bleeding at the moment - have got to hand some stuff in that I wouldn't normally be working on at all, and it's turning my mind inside out. If it is reasonably not badly received I may have some news for you soon ... But right now I haven't got the foggiest what I would use! Thanks for the small diversion though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the kind of syntactic framework Carnie's textbook is written in, the NP/DP *Fredrick* can**not** be an argument of (nor, consequently, receive a Theta role from) *consider* for **two** reasons: 1) because that would leave the one-place predicate *foolish* without the only (= subject) argument it **must** have, an obligatory Theta role of *foolish* would **not** be assigned to/discharged by anything, and the **Theta Criterion would be violated**, and 2) because that would also require *consider* to be a **three**-place predicate, whereas, of course, *consider* **cannot** take, and assign Theta roles to, **three** arguments, as 'arguments' are defined in both logic and P&P linguistics (note that the 'secondary predicate' or 'predicative' that alternative syntactic theories would claim to exist in *Wilma considers Fredrick **foolish*** would  **not** be a third 'argument' of *consider*, but a 'predicate' of *Fredrick*).

As to why *Fredrick* **must** become the subject of the passive clause (iii) *Frederick is considered t to be foolish*, the reason is that, otherwise, *Fredrick* would receive **no Case** and would **violate the Case Filter**. That, in its turn, follows from the fact that passive participles like *considered* can**not** assign accusative Case (nor any other Case) to their  complements. When the complement of *consider* is a clause, as in (iii), the clause itself causes no Case Filter violation, as clauses do **not** need Case, but an NP/DP object **does** need accusative Case. If *consider* is **not** made passive, as in (ii), *Fredrick* can, indeed, receive accusative Case from it, no Case problem arises, and, therefore, *Fredrick* **need not** move from its 'deep' position of subject of the infinitive *to be foolish*. What's more, in such circumstances, *Fredrick* **cannot** move **at all** unless it is into a position in which no Case is assigned, e.g., the position of Topic, as in ***Fredrick***, Wilma considers __ to be rather foolish. However, if *consider* carries passive inflection, as in (iii), either *Fredrick* moves into a position in which it can receive **some** Case from another Case-assigner (here: nominative, from the Tense inflection of the higher verb *is*) or the sentence violates the Case Filter and is doomed to fail.

Finally, the Case requirement for NP/DPs also explains why  * *Fredrick to be foolish is considered ___ (by Wilma)* can**not** be a sentence of English: if the whole infinitival clause is 'moved' and made the subject of *is considered by Wilma*, the clause itself, of course, raises no Case problem, as explained, but its subject, *Fredrick*, **still remains Case-less** and violates the Case Filter, since a **non**-finite Infl cannot assign Case to an **overt** subject like *Fredrick*. If the subject is phonetically null, i.e., PRO, of course, no such Case Filter violation arises - either because null subjects require/support no Case, which seems reasonable, or because non-finite Infl assigns Null Case to PRO, depending on the theory of Case each Chomskian linguist adopts - and the result is well-formed, as in *PRO to be foolish is considered __ by Wilma a fatal flaw*.